# How is $\sum_{j=1}^n(X_j - \bar X)(X_j - \bar X)' = \sum X_jX_j' - n \bar X \bar X'$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

> Let $X_j$ be a column vectors of the same shape, $(\text{_})'$ indicates transposition,
>   and $\bar  X = \sum X_j / n $
>
> Prove $\sum_{j=1}^n(X_j - \bar X)(X_j - \bar X)' = \sum X_jX_j' - n
> \bar X \bar X'$

I see that

$\sum_{j=1}^n(X_j - \bar X)(X_j - \bar X)' = \sum(X_j - \bar X) X_j' + (\sum(X_j-\bar X))(-\bar X)' $ but from here I get $\sum X_jX_j' - \sum \bar X X_j' - \sum X_j \bar X ' + n\bar X \bar X '$.  Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that for the second term $$\sum_j \bar{X}X_j'=\bar{X} \sum_j X_j'=\bar{X} (n\bar{X})'=n\bar{X}\bar{X}'.$$

Similarly for the third term.

Hopefully you can see how to simplify the equations from here.

Edit:

For the third term,

$$\sum_j X_j\bar{X}'= \left(\sum_j X_j\right)\bar{X}'= (n\bar{X})\bar{X}'=n\bar{X}\bar{X}'.$$

Hence combinining the last three terms, we have

$$-n\bar{X}\bar{X}'-n\bar{X}\bar{X}'+n\bar{X}\bar{X}'=-n\bar{X}\bar{X}'$$

Comment: Then for the third term I get $n \bar X' \bar X$ and the expression is: $\sum X_j X_j' -n \bar X \bar X' - n \bar X' \bar X + n \bar X \bar X'$ which reduces to $\sum X_j X_j ' - n \bar X ' \bar X. $ But the last expression isn't equal to $n \bar X \bar X '$.

Comment: i have included more details in the answer.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I factored incorrectly in the third term.